# Why Doesn't have any Class in Program.cs in .NET Core 5?

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I am trying to work with .NET 5 to update my information. So I started to review the *eShopOnContainers-ServicesAndWebApps* project [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers).

I have read its older versions (2.2 and 3.1) that is a rich sample with a lot of fantastic points. But [here](https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnContainers/blob/dev/src/Services/Identity/Identity.API/Program.cs) in .NET 5, at first glance, in `Program.cs`, I see a lot of methods and properties without any classes which I can't understand and make me confused. How can we have methods without class in a cs file?

Comment: [C# 9 now has top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)

Comment: Wow! So it comes from C#9! It's weird!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a feature of C# 9: [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#top-level-statements)

> Top-level statements remove unnecessary ceremony from many applications.

> Only one file in your application may use top-level statements. If the compiler finds top-level statements in multiple source files, it’s an error. It’s also an error if you combine top-level statements with a declared program entry point method, typically a Main method. In a sense, you can think that one file contains the statements that would normally be in the Main method of a Program class.

So you can now write a program that contains only this line of code:

```
System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Thanks, David, so how can I call a method without Its class?

Comment: As long as it's in the same file, just call it like you would any other method.

Comment: What about calling it from another class?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking now.

Comment: I meant how can I call a method that is not contained by a class, inside another class to use it? Is it possible at all?

Comment: @Mohammad code compiled as internal class with name `<Program>$`, so you can't use it anywhere in program without reflection

Comment: That's my answer dude. Thanks

Comment: Ah, well you shouldn't be doing that anyway.

Comment: @DavidG: Why not? I had written a command-line program and it turned out later that it was convenient to call its ````public int Main(string[] args)```` method from another program. Why is that a problem?

Comment: @Mohammad: You can get access to the implicitly created `Program` class by adding 
````public partial class Program { }```` in the code of the top-level-statement file.

Comment: @ChristopherHamkins There's just no good reason to pollute your code like that. If you need some shared functionality, then put that in a class where it can be used by multiple things. That way you can test it properly. If you find you are calling the Main method from something else, your architecture is probably misaligned. It's fine for small, trivial apps, but anything more complex should be architected properly.